# Remove time stamp Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

Can I remove time stamp from a field in a Data extention?

I have a Persons table with the field a data field called **R_MGStart**, this field is a date field.

I have tried:
FormatDate(R_MGStart()) but that is not working

How do I remove the timestamp?

Comment: Is the date field set as required? Are you using SQL to alter it? You may need to add more explanation to your question.

Comment: I'm using SQL to alter it.

Comment: The date field is set as required in the data extention

Comment: What do you want to remove from the field? The time of day? Do you wanna change how this stores dates?

Comment: SELECT 
    a.PID,
    a.email,
    a.Name,
    a.CountryCode,
    a.PhoneMobile,
    a.InNewR_Dialog,
    a.R_MGStart (this is the datetime field that I want to populate without timestamp)
FROM
    Persons a 
LEFT JOIN 
    PersonsPostal b on a.PID = b.PID
WHERE etc.

Comment: When the Date field called `R_MGStart` is required by definition of the dataextension you cannot leave it blank / not fill it.

Comment: Well, it cannot be set to "required" if you're wanting it removed. And you won't be able to change the format if the field-type is "date", as "date" has its own format. Once it's not required in your DE, change your SQL to exclude the date.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Only allows you to SELECT data in Marketing Cloud, so removing data from a field is not something a SELECT will allow you to do. You can always delete single-record data from a data extension using Contact Builder, but if you're looking to do it en masse with SQL there's a hacky way to do it:

Create an empty duplicate of your data extension where you copy over all your desired data, less the timestamp data in question. Then just copy it all back to the starting data extension.

Edit: You mention the data extension has this field as not nullable. You can't have null data in a field that's not nullable. You'd need to change the rule or duplicate the data into a different data extension where it is nullable.